# AFNetwork With Self Signed Certificate

Tags: rest, ssl, certificate, backend

I am trying to set up self signed SSL certificate for my IOS app which has a REST backend.

My question is should I use [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES]; when we use self signed certificates? And NO with trusted certificates?

I didn't understand the exact mechanism however I read about SSL for hours.. It works with setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES but otherwise I get 1012 error.

Comment: It seems like you can not use self signed certificate with [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:NO] until somehow you install that certificate on the phone. In simulator you may drag & drop your cer file to install, and it works after that. I should go with Apple's trusted CAs I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should set [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES]; when using self signed certificates. And correct; you should use NO with trusted certificates.

You are likely still getting the error when it is set to NO because a part of your certificate chain is not trusted. Try using an app called SSL Detective to make sure the entire chain is trusted with no red (untrusted) components. AFNetworking doesn't like those.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is should I use [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES]; when we use self signed certificates? And NO with trusted certificates?

No! This would defeat the whole purpose of SSL because it would make man-in-the-middle attacks possible. Better use [public key pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning). I don't know how to do this with AFNetwork, but the linked resource has code for lots of environments.

Comment: Those posts claim the otherwise by the way. But that didn't seem safe to me either; 

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1944

http://initwithfunk.com/blog/2014/03/12/afnetworking-ssl-pinning-with-self-signed-certificates/

Comment: It might be that this option is badly named and just means that it will not do the built-in checks but you might define others. In other languages this kind of option usually disables all checks, i.e. built-in and custom checks. But better check that it really uses pinning at the end. In no case you should set this option and then don't do any further checks because then you would just accept any certificates.